# How to formulate / solve a multi-commodity flow problem with dependent flow between commodities to plan harvesting operations

Tags: network-flow

I am working on a multi-commodity flow problem to conduct tactical harvesting planning. The idea is to model the crop and the machinery as commodities. Crop move from field to being harvested and harvesters move between depot and fields. The flow and cost of the crop is dependent on the integer flow of the machinery. I present a more formal description of the problem below. I am trying to figure out a way to model this problem and appreciate any help. In this regard, I have two questions regarding the problem:

1. How do you call the network problem I describe when commodity flows are interdependent and used to plan sequential commodity flow? In addition, how do you call it when adding more "stages" e.g. transportation from field to factory?

2. How do I define the harvester flow in a way that harvesters move correctly and efficiently through the network? (I have problems in setting the harvesters up, make them move, meeting the demand constraint, while complying with the crop flow.)

**Model Formulation:**

For a basic multi-commodity flow formulation of the crop harvesting problem, suppose the two commodities are beets and harvesters. The beets are given as $b_{irrt}$ where $r\in \{f,h\}$ with $f$ for on the field, $h$ for harvested, $i$ indicates the field and $t$ the time-period. We assume $b_{iff0}$ is the given total quantity on field $i$ and $b_{irr0}=0$ for all other $irr$. The harvester flows are given as $h_{ijt}$, $i$ and $j$ for beginning and ending locations (can include) $i=j$ at time $t$. Harvesters start moving from a depot.

**Objective Function**

Suppose the operating costs are $c^h_{ij}$ and harvester movement $h^h_{ijt}$, then the deterministic model is:

\begin{equation}\label{obj}
\min \sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{i}\sum_j\ \sum_{h}c^h_{ijt} h^h_{ijt}
\end{equation}

**Crop Flow**

\begin{eqnarray}
  b_{ifft} &=& b_{iff,t-1}-b_{ifht}, \label{eq1}\\
  b_{ihht} &=& b_{ihh,t-1}+b_{ifht}. \label{eq2}\\
\end{eqnarray}

**Harvester Flow**

Suppose the depot is at position 0. Then all harvesters starting at the depot is given by:

\begin{eqnarray}
   h_{000} &=& 1 \label{eq3}
\end{eqnarray}

All harvesters leave to one field at $t=1$

\begin{eqnarray}
  \sum_{i} h_{0i1} &=& 1 \label{eq4}
\end{eqnarray}

**Demand Constraint**

In total, we need at least $D$ harvested beets per $t$.

\begin{eqnarray}
  \sum_{i \in I} b_{ifht} &\geq& D \quad \forall t > 1 \label{eq5}
\end{eqnarray}

**Relationships Between Commodities**

The commodities are related by the following constraints where $\bar{H}_i$ is the max harvesting rate of a harvester.

\begin{eqnarray}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
 b_{ifht} &=& \bar{H}h_{iit}\label{eq6} 
\end{eqnarray}